# replace all but first space occurence between 2 paterns in lines

Tags: awk, sed

example of input file:

```
LINE1 LINE1 M) W1 W2 W3}N) REST
LINE2 LINE2 SOME OTHER WORDS
LINE3 LINE3 LINE3 M) Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4}N) REST
```

in matched lines between patterns M) and N) I need to replace all spaces but the first one, expected output is:

```
LINE1 LINE1 M) W1W2W3}N) REST
LINE2 LINE2 SOME OTHER WORDS
LINE3 LINE3 LINE3 M) Z1Z2Z3Z4}N) REST
```

Comment: If perl is available to  you try: `perl -pe 's/(?<=\s[A-Z][0-9])\s//g' inputFile`

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'match($0, /(M\) )(.+N\))/, a){
         gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "", a[2]);
         sub(/M\) .+N\)/, a[1] a[2])
     }1' file
```

The output:

```
LINE1 LINE1 M) W1W2W3}N) REST
LINE2 LINE2 SOME OTHER WORDS
LINE3 LINE3 LINE3 M) Z1Z2Z3Z4}N) REST
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'match($0,/M) .*N)/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/ +/,"",val);sub("M)","M) ",val);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);next} 1'  Input_file
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
match($0,/M) .*N)/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  gsub(/ +/,"",val);
  sub("M)","M) ",val);
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);
  next}
1
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
LINE1 LINE1 M) W1W2W3}N)REST
LINE2 LINE2 SOME OTHER WORDS
LINE3 LINE3 LINE3 M) Z1Z2Z3Z4}N)REST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed :

```
sed -E ':A;s/(.*M\) )([^ ]*)( )(.*N\).*)/\1\2\4/;tA' infile
```